# Android Emulator is very slow only if Android Studio is opened

Tags: performance, android-studio, ubuntu, android-emulator

Actually in this case all system is quite slow but the emulator is extremely slow.
Hardware acceleration is enabled, emulator works just fine if I close Android Studio.

The OS is Ubuntu 18.04

Any ideas how to fix this?

P.S. I did read all recommendations regarding emulator performance and it works fine until I start Android Studio.

Comment: I just asking. Have you enabled VTx(Virtualization)?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Tools > AVD Manager > Edit a specific Device > show Advanced Settings > 
1. reduce RAM
2. Make sure your using Quick Boot
3. Enable Multi-Core CPU

Answer (score 0):

For me it was completely different I was getting some data from a node server which I forgot to start.  The php was delivering the date so could not see  the problem on UI.  Just started the node server and it was fixed.

Check all server side starts.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Ubuntu 20.04, Nvidia GPU) it was hardware rendering not being auto-enabled, so I had to manually enable. After that the emulator was very smooth.

Device Manager > find your device > Edit > Emulated Performance / Graphics > Hardware - GLES 2.0